# Python [WinError 2] on exisiting directory, vanishes after manually opening directory

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

I have a weird reproducable problem on my Windows 10 machine:
When I try to programmatically access a specific network directory (//europe.example.corp/path_to_dir/) via Python, e.g. open a Windows file browser window out of Python by using the command

```
os.startfile
```

I sometimes cannot access it with WinError 2, even though the directory exists. But after I manually open the directory with the Windows file browser, accessing it through Python suddenly works.
This happens at reproducable rates. My guess is, it has something to do with rights, but I am not sure how to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

It often happens after restarts of the system. After I once open the desired directory manually by using the Windows file browser, the error doesn't appear anymore for several hours/days/until restart?